# How do I add music to an iPhone from a Mac laptop without replacing the library on either device?

Tags: iphone, mac, music, library

I am trying to add music from a laptop running MacOS 12.4 to an iPhone 7 running 15.5. When I try to do this no matter which options I select, I get a message saying that syncing the two devices will replace media on another library, I guess because I can only sync with one computer at a time? (I already synced another iPhone.) Is there a way around this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Is your iPhone set to be manually synced?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Thanks Jaime. Do you mind telling me or sharing a link for how to do that?

Comment: Nevermind, it presents you with the same problem. @Tetsujin it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes/Music will only sync tunes from the library it's connected to. Swap computers, swap libraries, it will not merge, it will overwrite. It may play havoc with other things you expect to sync too, photos etc.

The only way to achieve what you want is to get all the tunes onto the Mac it is normally synced to.

Comment: Thanks, so there's no other way around this like a third party app etc?

Comment: Third party apps can pull an entire backup then pick it apart, so long as you have the right passwords. None of them can really push/pull data  to & from an iPhone [other than simple 'files/documents' to sandboxed areas, which you can already do with iTunes, email or airdrop etc] - that would be a serious security concern. You really don't want to try syncing a phone to more than one Mac, even if you own them both.